# Show that $\operatorname P\left[\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}\left(M_s-\frac\alpha2[M]_s\right)\ge\alpha\beta\right]\le e^{-\alpha\beta}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a complete probability space and $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a complete filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$.

Let $(M_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a local $\mathcal F$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$X^\sigma:=\sigma M-\frac{\sigma^2}2[M]\;\;\;\text{for }\sigma\in\mathbb R.$$ By the Itō formula, $$N^\sigma:=e^{X^\sigma}=N_0+\sigma N\cdot M\tag1$$ is a local $\mathcal F$-martingale for all $\sigma\in\mathbb R$.

> Assume $M$ is right-continuous. I want to show that $$\operatorname P\left[\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}X^\alpha_s\ge\alpha\beta\right]\le e^{-\alpha\beta}\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ and }\alpha,\beta>0.\tag2$$

If $M$ is a (strict) $\mathcal F$-martingale, then [we can show that $N^\sigma$ is an $\mathcal F$-martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3726755/47771) as well and hence we obtain $$\operatorname P\left[\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}\ge a,[M]_t\le b\right]\le\operatorname P\left[\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}N^\sigma_s\ge e^{\sigma a-\frac{\sigma^2}2b}\right]\le e^{\frac{\sigma^2}2b-\sigma a}\tag3$$ by Doob's martingale inequality for all $t\ge0$ and $a,b>0$.

> Are we able to show $(3)$ even when $M$ is only a *local* $\mathcal F$-martingale? If that would be the case, we might be able to show $(2)$ by noting that $$M_s-\frac\sigma2[M]_s\ge a-\frac{\sigma^2}b\Leftrightarrow N^\sigma_s\ge e^{\sigma a-\frac{\sigma^2}2b}\tag4$$ for all $s\ge0$ and $a,b,\sigma\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Is $M$ a *continuous* local martingale?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Feel free to assume that it is continuous, but do you think it is necessary?

Comment: The stochastic exponential of a local martingale takes a different form when that local martingale has jumps.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Could you clarify your terminology? I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Are you saying that $(1)$ is incorrect, if $M$ is not continuous?

Comment: The stochastic exponential of a semimartingale $Z$ is the process $\mathcal E(Z)_t:=\exp(Z_t-(1/2)[Z]^c_t)\prod_{0<s\le t}(1+\Delta Z_s)\exp(-\Delta Z_s)$, where $[Z]^c$ is the continuous part of the quadratic variation of $Z$. If $Z$ is a local martingale, then so is $\mathcal E(Z)$. So the claim (1) needs $M$ to be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $M$ is continuous, the process $Y:=\exp(X^\alpha)$ is a non-negative local martingale, with initial value $1$; in particular, $Y$ is a non-negative supermartingale. You then have, taking $T$ to be the first time $X^\alpha$ is at least $\alpha\beta$:
$$
1=\Bbb E[Y_0]\ge
\Bbb E[Y_T; T<\infty]\ge \exp(\alpha\beta)\cdot\Bbb P[T<\infty].
$$Finally, notice that $\{T<\infty\}=\{\sup_{s\ge 0}X_s^\alpha\ge\alpha\beta\}\supset \{\sup_{0\le s\le t}X^\alpha_s\ge\alpha\beta\}$.

Comment: "with initial value $1$", if $M_0=0$ a.s.. I guess you're assuming that.